# Turning switch on lowers voltage from 5.2v to 3.0v

Tags: pi-4, power, power-supply, battery, power-management

This is probably a simple question, but I’ve researched a lot and haven’t been able to figure out how to fix the problem.

Basically, I have a Raspberry Pi and a 5-inch LCD screen wired to a toggle switch (not a push button). The switch is wired to a voltage booster, which is in turn wired to a 3.7v Lopo battery. Hopefully you understand all that lol it’s pretty confusing.

Here is a link to a few pictures for reference: https://photos.app.goo.gl/voJADXQnme8qpX8VA

So I adjusted the potentiometer on the voltage booster to supply 5.2v output before wiring everything up. I wired everything up, and now when I flip the switch the voltage immediately drops from down to about 3.0v! Which is strange because even my battery can provide 3.7v. Once I flip the switch to the off position everything goes back to 5.2v.

Is there any reason why this is happening? Maybe it’s because the wires I’m using are thin (they are just jumper wires)? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the booster is probably not able to supply the necessary current and becomes overloaded

Comment: if in doubt about the wires, then measure the voltage between the two ends of each wire when the RPi is powered on

Comment: Ok, I tried wiring the screen and raspberry pie directly and got the same result. This means that the voltage booster I’m using can’t supply enough current I think. It’s still strange that the voltage goes down to 3.0v though. Why is that? @jsotola

Comment: refer to the power supply datasheet about the power supply behavior during an overload

Comment: Please give us the wiring details in [schematic form](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question) instead of  a verbal description and a photograph. Neither are clear.

Comment: If the booster uses a silcon diode it would drop 0.7V, which explains why you get 3.0V.